# MySQL Query: ID not equal and with multiple LIKE operator not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE ID<>@id AND Tags LIKE @tag1 OR Tags LIKE @tag2
```

ID <> @id not working.

Replace "OR Tags LIKE @ tag2" >
"AND Tags LIKE @ tag2" works when I do, but my query should work as "OR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE ID <> @id AND (Tags LIKE @tag1 OR Tags LIKE @tag2);
```

If `@tag1` and `@tag2` have no wildcards, then use `in` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE ID <> @id AND Tags IN (@tag1, @tag2);
```